# 401 error calling REST service from mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, credentials

I am trying to make a request to a REST method and recieve the data in XML but this all goes well but when i want to use credentials for a method, because for this method you need to give credentials.

https://handshake:16a144bc5f480692d5c8d926068d2db5@rest-api.pay.nl/v2/Transaction/getStatus/xml/?orderId=236750347X6d2ee7

But when i use this one in the browser it work but this is not working from my controller.

```
    // 
    // GET: /Home/Succes
    public ActionResult Succes(string orderId)
    {
        string token = PaymentCalls.Login();
        ViewBag.Token = token;

        string _URL = "https://handshake:" + token + "@rest-api.pay.nl/v2/Transaction/getStatus/xml/?orderId=" + orderId;

        NetworkCredential cr = new NetworkCredential("handshake", token);




        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(_URL);
        var output = from feed in doc.Descendants("data")
                     select new Status
                     {
                          amount = feed.Element("amount").Value,
                          consumerAccountNumber = feed.Element("consumerAccountNumber").Value,
                          consumerCity = feed.Element("consumerCity").Value,
                          consumerEmail = feed.Element("consumerEmail").Value,
                          consumerName = feed.Element("consumerName").Value,
                          consumerZipcode = feed.Element("consumerZipcode").Value,
                          countryCode = feed.Element("countrCode").Value,
                          entranceCode = feed.Element("entranceCode").Value,
                          ipAddress = feed.Element("ipAddress").Value,
                          orderId = feed.Element("orderId").Value,
                          statsAdded = feed.Element("statsAdded").Value,
                          paymentSessionId = feed.Element("paymentSessionId").Value,
                          result = feed.Element("result").Value,
                          statusAction = feed.Element("statusAction").Value
                     };



        return View(output);
```

So when we call this controller we get an 401 error but using the same url in the browser works. So i dont know but how can i set to pass credentials or something?

Comment: Have you tried attaching fiddler to see what the difference is in the HTTP request? http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: No, i did check it from google dev tools but i dont think it has to do with this because from my code exception it is a 401 error.

Comment: And i just need to know how i can pass credentials to this service because it is using basic authentication. So if  someone can give me the answer to this i realy would appriciate it

Comment: It is to do with this. 401 is a HTTP response so you need to analyse what the difference is in you HTTP requests. There is probably a HTTP header value or something that is missing or different. I'd attach Fiddler and compare the working HTTP request with the failing one. You can then look at fixing the underlying issue.